# Sorting course_numbers like sorting using natsort

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have these sample course_numbers

```
 cmsc 11
 cmsc 2
 cmsc 56
 cmsc 21
 cmsc 128
```

I use this query

```
SELECT * FROM subject ORDER BY LENGTH(`course_number`)
```

to natural sort the result

and it worked, but when i add these course_numbers

```
it 1
it 256
it 20
```

they kinda mess up.

What query should i use to order them like this

```
 cmsc 2
 cmsc 11     
 cmsc 21
 cmsc 56
 cmsc 128
 it 1
 it 11
 it 20
 it 100
 it 256
```

I've searched and saw 'case' on their select statements but I do not know how to use them

Comment: plz mention data type of both the columns

Comment: the datatype of the course_number btw is varchar(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider splitting up the both parts of your course number, since "CMSC"/"IT" is one Part (even with variable length), and the real number is another part. If you store the number in a number column (int), you could easily correct them.

so it would be

```
SELECT concat(course_type, " ", course_subnumber) as course_number, ...
from subject
order by course_type, course_subnumber
```

As long as you have a bit luck, you could try with you structure the following:

```
SELECT * from subject
order by left(course_number, 2), length(course_number), course_number
```

then you get only in trouble if different course_types start with the same two letters.

Comment: the second suggestion answered my question, so you limited the subject by just 2 letters and sorted it out by length and name. Never thought of that. Thanks @flaschenpost

Comment: You're welcome, but don't curse me if your Application has grown up some day and the trap snaps (courses with MSOFS and with MSDN will give funny order). Normally it's easier to change small design issues in an early state.

Comment: I'm helping my friend and she said if possible, she will not change the table. I'll just tell her to change the table if something is bothering her. thanks again for the warning :)